# Should you use setState when having RiverPod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I was wondering , since I started using RiverPod , if I should not use setState at all and have almost everything in StateNotifierProvider

Comment: `it's okay` if you are using `setState` with `riverpod` because the only thing setState does is calling build method. if your state is local like you don't need that state out side of that widget then it is preferable to `setState`(managing state of checkbox or switch in a fill up form) for `global` state use `rivepod`.

Comment: @Ruchit you should make that an answer so we can upvote it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to understand there are 2 types of state:

- Ephemeral(Local): This is contained to only a single widget and not used for passing information between different components. You should use `setState` and internal state variables for cases like these. Like @Ruchit said in his comment above, a good example is a checkbox, switch, dropdown. Or if you want to hide/show something based on some data.
- Global: This is for any information that is passed between layers, components or widgets and should be accessible and synced across different screens. For these cases you should use **state management** solutions like `Provider`, `Riverpod` etc. Some examples are:

  - Adding items to a cart.
  - Updating a favourites list.
  - Sending data to network layer to make http calls etc.